# Printf prints blank lines

Tags: bash

I have a bash script that gives me problems in writing on a file.

To do the question really simple, this is more or less the part of the script giving me troubles:

```
for bin in 0.0_0.10 0.10_0.235
    do
        for i in `seq 0 100`;
        do
            t_start=4403.26853
            printf "%f\n" $tstart >> $bin.txt
        done
    done
```

The result is text files with 100 blank lines.

If I change `%f` to `%s` or put the quotes at `$tstart` anything changes.

What am I missing?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Look at the variable names. t_start and tstart:

> t_start=4403.26853
>
> printf "%f\n" $tstart >> $bin.txt